# How can I resolve "Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value" in FlowType?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The following function signature:

```
type SaveComplete = {
  id: string
};

const handleReduce = ((state, { payload: { id } }: Action<SaveComplete>) => {
   // `id` is used unconditionally
};
```

...results in the following FlowType error:

```
property `id`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Would this help you https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3059?

Comment: Thank you. Having reviewed that I m still unable to understand the problem. I am so new to FlowType the vocabulary they use is impenetrable to me.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was that the type for `Action` had not been imported into the file.